# How to convert decimal to hex in string format

Tags: python, string

Hi let's say I have 5 decimal numbers.How can I convert them firstly to hexadecimal and to string afterwards. Is there any built in function for this? I tried below

```
numbers = [123,46,0,11,6]
for number in numbers:
    print(hex(number).lstrip("0x").upper())
```

Expected output is

```
7B
2E
00
0B
06
```

but the result is

```
7B
2E

B
6
```

Comment: `strip` will remove all characters inside the string you give it as an argument. So `"0x00".strip("0x")` will leave you an empty string. Just slice the string like `hex(number)[2:]`

Answer (score 0):

Add `zfill`:

```
numbers = [123,46,0,11,6]
for number in numbers:
    print(hex(number).lstrip("0x").zfill(2).upper())
```

Comment: It's much simpler with format: `format(number, "02X")`.

Comment: Nice. That's worth a separate answer.